# Long-line handling from Nano in Vim?

Tags: vim, nano

I'm a hardcore VIM-user. However, I wonder whether it's possible to configure VIM to provide a lone-line handling like Nano. Imagine the following text file:

```
1 This is a short line
2 This is a much much much much much much much (...) much longer line
```

When I open it in VIM, and like to get to the end of the second line, it's displayed like this (with ■ being where the cursor is):

```
1 ort line
2 ch much much much much much much (...) much longer line■
```

When I open in Nano, and navigate to the end of the second line, only this specific line is displayed "shifted", like so:

```
1 This is a short line
2 >h much much much much much much (...) much longer line■
```

Can I do this with VIM too?

Comment: I don't think so but that would be an interesting feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim is a fixed-width text editor. The problem with your suggested visualization is that when moving to a previous / next line (e.g. via `k` / `j`), the cursor would "jump" horizontally on the screen, instead of going straight up.

One could get accustomed to that (the cursor already jumps when the new line is shorter (unless `'virtualedit'` is set)), but how would a blockwise visual selection be represented? With jagged edges on both sides?

That's why it's unlikely to be accepted, but don't let this discourage anyone from writing the (non-trivial) patch :-)